# evoPDF Conversion fails when using HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, pdf, ssl

I am trying to use the evoPDF HTML to PDF converter on an Azure web application, but I seem to have issues that only occur when the site is being visited through HTTPS.

My azure deployment has my SSL certificate installed and working for my domain.

If I try to convert while visiting the secure site, the resulting PDF only has the content of the _Layout.cshtml view, and without any stylesheet applied.

If I try again going through the cloudapp.net url, I get a certificate error on my browser as expected, but the resulting PDF comes out perfectly.

That's tested using the exact same page, with the exact same code.
Only difference as far as I can tell is the HTTP/s.

I've crawled the evoPDF site, and checked for others having similar issues, but I can't find any that appear to come close.

As soon as I find my PO number for the licence I will email the evoPDF team for support, but until then I'm hoping someone here might be able to shed some light on the issue.

Just for info -- I'm only converting my own cshtml files by passing the html string from the view engine to the converter.

The code runs perfectly on my local machine, perfectly in azure staging but not in production (UAT).

Comment: Are you providing the https base url for evopdf so it knows where your relative css paths are coming from? Also is your css under https as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm providing both the BaseUrl and the LinksBaseUrl - both of which are using the HTTPS base url.
I'm testing some variations where I'm deliberately swapping HTTPS to HTTP, as the converter seems to work fine when the site isn't using HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the special [EVO HTML to PDF Converter for Azure](http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx) solution or the general [HTML to PDF for .NET Library](http://www.evopdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx)? The general library does not work with Azure websites, it works only with cloud services and virtual machines. For Azure websites you have to use the special solution for Azure mentioned above.